# Is any non-Hermitian $(N\times N)$ matrix with $N$ eigenvectors diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that any Heritian matrix is diagonalizable, however I am trying to find when a non-Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable.

Is it enough that there are $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors if the matrix is $N\times N$?

Also can the same method be applied to these non-hermitian matrices (those that are diagonalizable) as the hermitian matrices, i.e. writing $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is made of the eigenvectors etc.

Comment: Indeed, a size $N$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if we can find $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: And we can use the same method to diagolize it, regardless of the fact that it's not hermitian?

Comment: The fundamental difference with Hermitian matrices is that when $A$ is Hermitian, $P$ can be chosen to have orthonormal columns. If you're using $P^{-1}$, yes: the same method applies.

Comment: Ok thanks @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @Omnomnomnom do you mean that it should be $A = P^{-1}DP$?

Comment: If $P$ is the matrix whose columns are $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then $A = PDP^{-1}$, which is to say that $P^{-1}AP = D$.

Comment: Right of course...thanks again.

Comment: Note that $ \langle \lambda_1 v, w \rangle = \langle Av, w \rangle = (Av)^H w = v^H Aw = \langle v, Aw \rangle = \langle v, \lambda_2 w \rangle $ for eigenvectors $ v, w $ of a Hermitian matrix, and since the eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real, if $ \lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2 $ we have $ \langle v, w \rangle = 0 $, showing that the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to have $ n $ linearly independent eigenvectors for the matrix to be diagonalizable. As an example which is not Hermitian, consider the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Solving $ (1 - \lambda)^2 = 4 $, we find that the eigenvalues are $ \lambda = 3 $ and $ \lambda = -1 $, and the corresponding eigenvectors $ (2, 1)^T $ and $ (2, -1)^T $, which are linearly independent. Therefore, we conclude that our matrix is diagonalized as

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $$